# Please reopen my question on Travel Documentaries?

Tags: discussion, support

Would someone please advise how [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27259/travel-documentaries-or-videos-presenting-both-the-urban-and-rural) can be improved or emended or sharpened? 
I tried to include details and didn't perceive it as "too broad," so would be grateful for a reopening.

**Update Nov 13 2014**: Would someone please click the Reopen button for me, [prevented by my fledging reputation](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1910/13759)?

Comment: DId you flag it for a mod?

Answer (score 5):

In the event your question is put on hold, you need to edit your question, and then click 'reopen' on the question page.  That way a vote is triggered in the community whether or not to reopen it.

As I see it now, you're still asking about documentaries over several countries and many areas - hundreds of which have been made, as as per the rules - "there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format" is considered too broad.

Comment: Thanks. `then click 'reopen' on the question page`: Where can I find this? Is it only for users with > 10k rep?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal ah, you need [250 rep to cast a reopen vote on your own question].  You can always click flag and get a mods attention, if you feel your edits are now appropriate.

Comment: And don't forget to read the [help] to ensure it's on topic and meets the rules.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a "borderline" question to me.

This is a travelling, not a "coach surfing" or "culture" site. So if you are talking about "visiting" far away places by viewing documentaries, that's not quite on topic.

What you need to do is to coach your question in terms of a trip that you actually PLAN to make. Then you can say, I'm planning to visit [Place X] in [Y months'] time; could you recommend any documentaries that will help me prepare for my upcoming trip. Even here, you ought to be " more specific" about what you want to "bone up" on; urban vs. rural sites, ancient vs. modern sites, etc.

Comment: Yeah, recommending is not the best one to suggest, given that recommendations are strictly off topic / too broad, unless you're *reallllly* specific (I know you said that, I just wanted to emphasise this point)