# Please edit or rewrite 'How to plan for road trip in Canada productively ...?'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I've truly tried to improve https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38929/13759, but my  imperfect, rudimentary English seems to have impaired my repeated attempts thus far. So would someone please edit, elucidate, or rewrite it for me?
 A third-party review will clear my writing block.

Please feel free to edit my writing in that question directly, or post your rendition here. I want to add that I'm aiming to do this road trip during Christmas holidays so would relish more resources ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: [How do I reopen a question?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/click-reopen-on-the-question-page) - remember, you can flag it for a mod.

Answer (score 3):

Have you had a look at the help center? It gives a good indication as to what we expect.

For example, half way through your edited version about Canada, you also welcome videos on any other country.  This immediately makes it way too broad, with way too many possible answers. I've edited that out for you.

Definitely have a look at the help - and when you feel you meet the critera in there, flag it for a moderator to look.  Of course, remember, they'll be using the criteria there, so if you don't meet it, don't expect it to be reopened just because you've edited it.

Comment: Thank you for your edits!

Comment: Thank you again. Would you mind rewriting or editing my post for me, due to my rudimentary English? Please see my updated OP above?

Comment: As has been discussed in most, if not all of your meta posts, as well as on the questions, your English is not the problem. It's better than most.  It's the content of your question not fitting the parameters of the site.  See my [other answer below](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1925/101), which I took a lot of time to outline what YOU need to do to get it reopened.  Yes your trip is soon, but we have to work within the framework of the site.

Answer (score 2):

An extra answer, which seems appropriate, since you've now asked:

['Click 'reopen' on the question page'?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/click-reopen-on-the-question-page)

[Please reopen my question on Travel Documentaries?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/please-reopen-my-question-on-travel-documentaries)

and [this current question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38483/13759), all essentially the same on getting the same question reopened.

Asking people on meta to reopen your question, while possibly effective, is not the right way to go about it.

There are three paths to getting a question reopened.

1. Fix the question, as per suggestions you've had in the comments (**which you've not addressed yet**), and wording in the [help] center, AND at least one answer on meta. Initial edits on a question usually automatically suggest a reopen to the review queue, for more experienced users to approve.  As this must have already have happened, they've presumably been declined, so it's not enough.
2. Click 'reopen' after an edit, to FORCE a review. This isn't available to you yet, as explained, you don't have enough rep.
3. Flag it for a mod to reopen. If you've done this and it's not been reopened, it still doesn't fit the criteria, in the mod's opinion, and hopefully they've commented.

IF you really think you've addressed all the suggestions, then you could open a discussion on meta as to **why you believe your question is on topic** - (NOT 'what's wrong?' which you've already done 3-4 times), despite the close votes.  Alternatively, you can hop into the chat room and ask for some suggestions there.

Repeating the same request in the same way will simply get you the same outcome. Asking people to reopen *might* work, but **since you've not followed the suggested processes** that multiple people have explained, most people are now going to just shrug and move along.

Sorry if that is frustrating, but the processes are there for a reason!

Comment: Thanks. I deleted my comment because I thought to accept your kind suggestion here: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1934/13759