# How to improve 'How to find audiovisual travel guides for Canada productively?'?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Based on user Mark Mayo's numerous generous [posts](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1925/13759), I am here adopting his suggestion to `open a discussion on meta as to why you believe your question is on topic, despite the close votes.`

Would someone please explain and enlarge on `suggestions you've had in the comments which you've not addressed` and `you've not followed the suggested processes`?

Please advise; I'd appreciate a reopening and objective feedback. I did consider and use the aforestated suggestions to improve my question, so are there other areas of improvement?

**Update Nov 21 2014:** Please pardon my rudimentary English. User Gayot Fow wrote:

> **[1.]** ... you're not after something pursuant to travel in the sense of a contemplated trip. In fact nothing suggests there's a concrete objective underlying your query.
>
> ... **[2.]**... you're excluding those able to offer real-world experience

As regards **[1.]**, I confirm that I'm pursuing a trip in Canada. Does this clarify? **[2.]** In fact, I do want real-world experience such as those 3 links, so what's the concern? I never meant to exclude experience.

Comment: No..no..that's...not what I was suggesting.  The suggestion was "open a discussion on meta as to **why you believe your question is on topic, despite the close votes**.".

Comment: I've tried, and every time you've ignored the key part, IN BOLD, - **why YOU believe your question is on topic**.  You even skipped it in your quote.  I now defer to others to try to help. All the best.

Comment: Also, as an aside - 'pursuant'? 'Effusive'? 'Munificent'? Even I had to look the last one up and I'm a native English speaker.  It's great to play with advanced words, but it does exclude a portion of your readership who may not want to consult with a thesaurus just to understand your question.

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks. I didn't intend the words to exclude; my English is imperfect so I might've misused words. For example, I thought 'pursuant' was intuitive enough because it relates to 'pursue'. I've changed them now. I'll return to your earlier comment earlier, now that I think that I understand it.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your original question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38483/how-to-find-audiovisual-travel-guides-for-canada-productively and saw that you're not after something pursuant to travel in the sense of a contemplated trip or where advice from a 'road warrior' is useful.  In fact nothing suggests there's a concrete objective underlying your query.

Rather it appears that you want to do some open-ended home research which entails watching lots of videos made by people who went to Canada.  While travel enthusiasts may be sympathetic, or even of marginal help, you're excluding those able to offer real-world experience.  To be specific, you are asking for expertise about how to use Google (Yahoo, etc). That would make your question 'off topic'.

If that's the case, you may have to grapple with the notion that another Stack Exchange may be more appropriate for this question.  Something along the lines of television enthusiasts or video collectors or RSS feeds.  Those interest groups may be more receptive.

The tone suggested by your language hasn't been helping either.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please clarify your answers in my updated OP, due to my basic English?

Comment: @UpvoteLawArea51Proposal, done

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at your question again, and imho, there are multiple problems:

1) You seem to be asking more than 1 question. You seem to look for videos made by people traveling through Canada who just report their experience. At the same time, you look for advice how to plan and organize a trip.

2) As Gayot Fow already pointed out, it remains unclear what exactly the problem is. In the current form, it looks like you need just help to google.

3) Some parts of the question remain quite unclear. For example your last point. Your looking for "text descriptions for place names". I have no idea what this is.

Comment: +1 for identifying that it's about Google and having the yarbles to say it