# 'Click 'reopen' on the question page'?

Tags: discussion

> https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1742/13759 says:
>
> In the event your question is put on hold, you need to edit your question, and then click 'reopen' on the question page. That way a vote is triggered in the community whether or not to reopen it.

Yet I don't see any such 'reopen' option. Is this because of my relatively low rep? In this case, how do I request reopening of a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You unfortunately need 250 rep to do so.  You can still flag it for a moderator if you believe you now meet the criteria in the help center.