# Are questions on travel videos on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[My questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/13759) were sadly deemed off-topic, but [this recent, highly upvoted one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/56377/13759).

So can my closed questions please be made compatible with this website, because they would patently benefit users like this recent one?

Comment: The highly upvoted one had massively laser-like focus. There was a single answer which was factually correct, and only one answer. Nothing about the question called for someone to use their opinion.  Yours failed on those three points.  That's the difference IMHO

Answer (score 1):

> Are questions on travel videos on topic?

Yes, potentially. You have already given an example in your question.

> So can my closed questions please be made compatible with this website, because they would patently benefit users like this recent one?

Yes, potentially, by you. Other users are generally willing to help but at the same time reluctant to make radical edits that may end up with an on-topic question but one that is too far divorced from what you want answered.